# Dynamically loading html and clearing DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile

So I'm working with a few multipage Jquery Mobile documents that I want to be able to navigate between but not leave the WebView created by the mobile web app and still have the transitions. I've come across Todd Thomson's subpage widget and basically couldn't understand how to set everything up (visual learner and there are no template or demos on his github, no worries Todd if your out there).

So my question is, when you navigate from `index.html` to a multipage Jquery mobile document,`page1.html` via ajax is it possible to clear out what remains from the `index.html` and load the rest of the `page1.html` after the transition?

Answer (score 0):

When you link from index.html to page1.html which is a mutli page document you need to add the attribute **rel="external"** to the link. This clears out the dom for you to allow linking between the multiple pages in the document via the # anchors.